# Insert and Delete operation not working while using connected layer in ADO.NET

Tags: .net, ado.net

I have written a simple class that select, insert and delete from a mssql compact database.
I used the connected layer in ADO.NET. But unfortunately the select blcok of codes works but the inserting and deleteing block of codes doesnt work like i expect.
when I run the insert or delete operation I dont see any change in the database. But the code runs succesfully. I been trying to figure out this for days now.
This is the code below.

```
class Logic
    {
        SqlCeConnection con = null;

        //code the constructor of the class
        public Logic() { 
            //now we are going to collect the database configuration string
            string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectedCrud.Properties.Settings.DatabaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

            con = new SqlCeConnection(connectionString);

            Console.WriteLine(con.Database);
        }

        //This method is going to delete from the database
        public void deleteValue(int r){
            int k = 0;
            string sql = string.Format("delete from Details where id = {0}",r);
            using (SqlCeCommand command = new SqlCeCommand(sql, this.con)){
                try
                {
                    //open the connection 
                    this.con.Open();
                    k = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                }
                finally{
                    this.con.Close();
                }
            }

            if (k > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The rows as been deleted");
            }
            else
                Console.WriteLine("The row was not deleted");

        }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this is PHP?

Comment: was your k > 0? also what is the id column is it int or varchar?